# How Do I Resolve the "Cannot convert the pivot key value All to the data type of the pivot key column" Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to pivot some data that looks like this:

```
DATETIME  TAGNAME VALUE
1/12/15   All     215
1/12/15   key1     32
1/12/15   key2     28
1/12/15   key3     34
1/12/15   key4     45
1/12/15   key5     18
1/12/15   key6     38
```

To data that looks like this:

```
DATETIME  key1   key2   key3   key4  key5   key6  all
1/12/15     32      28     34     45    18     38  215
```

When I do this pivot operation with Pivot Key of Tag Name, Set Key as DateTime and Pivot Value as Value, I get the error "Cannot convert the pivot key value All to the data type of the pivot key column". I have no idea why. I've created and re-created the pivot transform and get that error on the first output column, no matter what it is.

For reference, the datatypes here are DateTime for DateTime, String for Tagname and float for Value.

I'm stumped. Help!

Comment: Are you doing this with a query or with an SSIS transformation?

Comment: SSIS Transformation.

Comment: So it's not always on the "All" value, it's always on whichever value is first?   It's given you the error on other values?

Comment: Yep - errors on any value that was the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this:

```
--create table 
CREATE TABLE test_table1(
DATE_TIME datetime,
TagName varchar(10),
Value float
);

--insert sample values
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','All',215)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key1',32)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key2',28)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key3',34)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key4',45)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key5',18)
INSERT INTO test_table1(DATE_TIME,TagName,Value) VALUES ('1/12/15','key6',38)


--use pivot function to pivot the data as needed
SELECT *
FROM (select convert(varchar(8),DATE_TIME,101) as [DateTime],  --converting to date format
             TagName,
             [Value] 
from test_table1
) s
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR [TagName] IN ([key1],[key2],[key3],[key4],[key5],[key6],[All])
) as pvttable
```

[SQL Fiddle Pivot Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2173e/12/0)

I would use pivot function in your query itself, instead of having to use pivot transform in SSIS. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it is an excellent workaround - THANK YOU. I'd still love to know why the SSIS pivot transformation failed.

Comment: Definitely appreciate the upvote. Is there any reason you wouldn't be able to use the sql query directly? I just found a blog that might be helpful if you are still interested in doing it through SSIS: http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-use-pivot-transformation-in.html

Comment: Oh I did use the SQL and I greatly appreciate it. I hadn't considered a SQL Pivot and it works great. I'm just dealing with a lot of disparate data and I know my day is going to come when I need this tool, and would love to figure it out.

Comment: Sometimes, just writing a sql query is the most efficient way to go. :) I am glad that it worked out for you. I would try recreating a new package and try it again. Maybe it might work out for you this time! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot use any image sharing websites right now. Instead I am posting this as an answer. Is this how your pivot transformation setup?

[image: Pivot Transformation Example]

**Update**

It worked just fine for me. See below:

[image: Pivot Table Result]

Comment: That's exactly how it was set up. I have no idea why it didn't work.

Comment: Try dropping your target table and recreating it and see if it helps.